# ReactJS + Material UI: How to set default value to null/no date selection for Material-UI/Pickers <Calendar /> standalone component?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am currently using the standalone Calendar picker for a project, and am trying to figure out how to load the calendar with no value selected. Current set up for the Calendar picker looks like this:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
  <Calendar
    date={selectedDate}
    classes={{ progressContainer: classes.calendar }}
    onChange={handleDateChange}
    renderDay={renderDay}
    onMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
 ></Calendar>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I have attempted to set the value for "date" to null/empty string, but that seems to throw an error for the DateFnsUtils. Any idea how I could restrict the Calendar picker from auto-selecting a date?

Comment: Hello! Looking at the props of https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/Calendar it seems that it requires a valid date, therefore you cannot have it empty. As an alternative maybe you could initially use the DatePicker component and eventually switching to the Calendar once a date is selected

Comment: I am also looking for same.